# Applescript to forward email but preserve sender

Tags: mail.app, applescript

How can I make an Applescript that Mail.app on my Mac can run? When it encounters a message that is being sent to mac@email.com, I'd like it to redirect it to email@gmail.com, where the "From" field is NOT mac@email.com, but rather is the "From" field on the original email that was sent to mac@email.com.

E.g., I'm Joe Schmo and I send an email from joeschmo@joe.com to mac@email.com. Then the Apple Script runs and redirects that email to send it to email@gmail.com with the From tag as joeschmo@joe.com

I am planning on setting up a rule in my Mail app that runs this apple script when it encounters a message that is being sent to mac@email.com.

Note: the emails in this example are fake.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the "Redirect" option, under the Message menu. Actually, if I'm reading your question right, you should be able to do this entirely through a rule, with no Applescript needed.

Building from "[How to batch forward messages from Mail.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46089/how-to-batch-forward-messages-from-mail-app)", if you make a rule that targets emails sent to mac@email.com, just say "Redirect Message" to "email@gmail.com".

Example: [image: Imgur]

Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no definitive answer because it depends on your email provider.

Normally an email provider will refuse an email with a FROM: field that not matches with the logged-in user. And on the other hand: What you want is a job for your email provider - he could give you the possibility to forward a mail with a preserving FROM: field.

I can´t give you an applescript because I think you won´t will use it, because of a refusing email provider.

If you want to test the whole thing please you could do this via [telnet](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/889/Sending+or+viewing+emails+using+telnet).

Comment: Could you at least show me how to add the From tag so I can try it out?

Comment: Simply: before you type the "Subject: This is a test subject" line add a "FROM: SHORTNAME <EMAILADDRESS>" line. All others you could learn from the link above.

Comment: @RobertStephens: Well, you´ve asked and I answered  - no reply is rude. If my answer fits please accept the answer below or give me more details.